# Regulating the space of all surfaces by a cut on curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Consider compact connected surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with boundary given by a fixed unit circle. It seems the collection of all such surfaces is some infinite-dimensional space, comprising mostly of very 'jagged' surfaces. If I try to regulate this space by only considering surfaces whose gaussian curvature is bounded in norm by some $\kappa_0 > 0$, does the space become finite-dimensional in some topology? It's not quite clear to me what the natural topology to use here is, a candidate is the Hausdorff distance (though this seems a bit too degenerate), or an idea along the Earth-movers distance?

Comment: If I understand the intent, a "sufficiently smooth and small" deformation of such a surface is such a surface, and the space of "smooth, small" deformations is still infinite-dimensional. Physically, think of the fixed unit circle as a loop of wire, and the surface as a soap bubble spanning the loop as air is blown gently through the loop.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I have this intuition for, say, deformations whose ‘height’ above the loop is bounded by epsilon. But for bounded curvature fluctuations, my intuition is not so good, it seems plausible to me it could be finite dimensional. So I’d like to see some rigorous argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: Even among surfaces of rotation with fixed area, the space of surfaces of bounded curvature is infinite-dimensional.

---

Theorem 2.5 of [*A Symplectic Look at Surfaces of Revolution*](https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=ens-001:2003:49::103#472) asserts (in particular) a bijective correspondence between

- Smooth, functions $\varphi$ defined on $[0, 1]$, positive on $(0, 1)$ and satisfying
  $$
  \varphi(1) = 0,\qquad
  \varphi'(1) = -2,\qquad
  \varphi(0) = 1.
  $$
- Isometry classes of smooth, rotation-invariant Riemannian metrics of area $2\pi$ on a disk, bounded by a unit circle. In the construction of the paper, if $\tau$ denotes a real parameter for $[0, 1]$, the Gaussian curvature of the metric induced by $\varphi$ is $K = -\frac{1}{2}\varphi''(\tau)$.

For example, the quadratic polynomial $\varphi_{0}(\tau) = 1 - \tau^{2}$ correspods to a round unit hemisphere. The boundary circle is at $\tau = 0$. (If it's of interest, the metric embeds in Euclidean three-space as a surface of rotation if and only if $|\varphi'| \leq 2$.)

Now, if $\psi$ denotes an arbitrary smooth function in $[0, 1]$ that vanishes to order $2$ at both endpoints and satisfies $\sup |\psi''| < 2$, then the function $\varphi = \varphi_{0} + \psi$ induces a metric of metric of bounded, positive curvature. The space of $\psi$ is infinite-dimensional (e.g., take any smooth function absolutely bounded by $1$, integrate twice, and add a suitable cubic polynomial to ensure second-order vanishing at $\tau = 1$); distinct $\psi$ induce non-isometric metrics.

Comment: Thanks for this! Are you aware of any way (other than ~discretising space) of regulating the space of surfaces to be 'finite-dimensional' in some sense?

Comment: You're welcome! <> Offhand I'm afraid not. Is there a geometric motivation to the question you can share? ("No" is fine; it sounds as if you might be searching for a thesis problem.)

Comment: I dont quite have a geometric motivation but rather a physics one: QCD is a theory in which (morally) you integrate over the space of all connections of a SU(3) bundle. As far as I am aware, this is very difficult to make rigorous, and Yang Mills as a whole is not proven to exist. To get results, latticeQCD regulates the integral by discretising space, and in a certain limit, calculations seem to look like integrals over spaces of surfaces (Wilson loops constructed from plaquettes). I was just wondering if there’s any other way to tackle this problem of regulation